# Hosting a Website from Handover Code

Tags: web-hosting

After a falling out with a website design company, they handed over the code for us to take elsewhere, and I was wondering where I can learn how to host it myself? I understand it might be a steep learning curve but I appreciate any advice on how I can teach myself how to do this.

About the handover code:

In the root folder there are two folders called "__MACOSX" and "Hand Over Code Data". These each go into folders that successively give the date (e.g. first a folder called 2015, then March, then 23), and this final folder contains "DB", "themes" and "wp-content". Each folder apart from the root contains a .DS_Store file with no name.

Comment: The question sounds vague to me. When you are given code, I suggest looking at everything in its entirety, especially any text files (such as the README files) All the better if there are installation notes. You can learn a lot from documentation.

Answer (score 2):

__MACOSX folders contain the metadata that OS X stores about files on Windows-formatted partitions that don't support extended attributes. .DS_Store files do have a name, it's prepended with a . to be hidden on OS X systems. Again, this is for file attributes like Spotlight comments. All of this is irrelevant to your actual question.

wp-content indicates a Wordpress instance and once you have Wordpress set up you can replace the wp-content folder with this folder.

The DB folder probably contains a dump of the MySQL database (given this is Wordpress) therefore you need to import this into your database. This depends entirely on how the database has been exported and what software you are using for the MySQL database now.

Themes should be part of the wp-content.

Comment: You gave the user a dang good start to understanding what he needs!